# Pulseaudio + Qemu high cpu usage

Tags: qemu, pulseaudio

I am rerouting the audio input and output of a Qemu guest by using the following:

In Environment:

```
QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=pa 
QEMU_PA_SINK=some_sink 
QEMU_PA_SOURCE=some_source 
QEMU_AUDIO_DAC_FIXED_FREQ=48000 
QEMU_AUDIO_ADC_FIXED_FREQ=48000
```

*some_sink* is `pactl load-module module-null-sink` and *some_source* is a monitor of another null-sink.

I have also setup the default sampling rate of the hosts Pulseaudio to 48000 such that no resampling occurs:

*/etc/pulse/daemon.conf:*

```
default-sample-rate = 48000
```

Pulseaudio version:

```
$ pulseaudio --version
pulseaudio 13.99.1
```

The audio out is **NOT** output on the machine, but forwarded to another system for processing.

The setup works fine (there is audio in and out), but the Pulseaudio CPU usage (on an Intel Xeon 3.50GHz) as reported by *top* is constantly between 15%-30%, which to me seems like A LOT.
Not doing any resampling and just forwarding a byte stream seems to me like an inexpensive operation...

1. Is the high CPU usage expected in this setup - if yes, why?
2. How could I investigate/troubleshoot the reason of pulseaudio's high CPU usage?

Answer (score 0):

I get this too, although not all the time and only on the machine that actually plays the sound.

I have VMs running zoom, citrix that the play audio through my laptop. Periodically on my laptop CPU goes to 30% or so.

pulseaudio -k; pulseaudio -D; fixes the cpu usage until it happens again.

(Annoyingly, once this is done, citrix sound doesn't work until citrix is restarted)